# Javascript: canvas, blury image issue?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

so I was specting why there's a blury drawing of the image in the canvas 
when I press the D keyboard, everything else works fine. I don't know if there's something in the way I draw this image, and also the context or translate method. Thanks for your help

```js
var Imagen= { // image to load, and manipulate
 obj: null,
 ruta: null,
 cargar: function() {
  this.obj= new Image();
  //this.obj.src= '/C:/Documents and Settings/casa/Mis documentos/Mis imágenes/sprite.png';
  this.obj.src= 'https://s22.postimg.org/6r8uzrygh/sprite.png';
 },
 ini: [2, 1],
 fin: [22, 38],
 pos: [0, 1],
 auxy: [0, 1],
 vel: {
  des: 0.4,
  som: 0.1
 }
};
var Lienzo= { // this is the canvas
 obj: document.getElementById('lienzo'),
 ancho: 600,
 alto: 300
};
var Sombra= { // this is for the sprites
 fg1: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*0; // recortes de la imagen
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1; // recortes de la imagen
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg2: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*1;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg3: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*2;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg4: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*3;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg5: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*4;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg6: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*5;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg7: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*6;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg8: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*7;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg9: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*8;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg10: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*6;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= -Imagen.auxy[0] -22;
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.save();
  c.translate(0, 0);
  c.scale(-1 ,1);
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
  c.restore();
 },
 fg11: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*7;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= -Imagen.auxy[0] -22;
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.save();
  c.translate(0, 0);
  c.scale(-1 ,1);
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
  c.restore();
 },
 fg12: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*8;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= -Imagen.auxy[0] -22;
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.save();
  c.translate(0, 0);
  c.scale(-1 ,1);
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
  c.restore();
 }
};
var Animar= { // a=65, d=68, w=87, s=83 // izq=37, arr=38, der=39, abj=40 this is for calling the sprites
 S: 0,
 W: 0,
 A: 0,
 D: 0,
 tecla: 0, dir: 83,
 abajo: function() {
  
  if (this.S <= 1) Sombra.fg1();
  else if (this.S <= 2) Sombra.fg2();
  else if (this.S <= 3) Sombra.fg3();
  else if (this.S <= 4) Sombra.fg2();
  
  this.S+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.S > 4) this.S= 0;
 },
 arriba: function() {
  
  if (this.W <= 1) Sombra.fg4();
  else if (this.W <= 2) Sombra.fg5();
  else if (this.W <= 3) Sombra.fg6();
  else if (this.W <= 4) Sombra.fg5();
  
  this.W+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.W > 4) this.W= 0;
 },
 izquierda: function() {
  
  if (this.A <= 1) Sombra.fg7();
  else if (this.A <= 2) Sombra.fg8();
  else if (this.A <= 3) Sombra.fg9();
  else if (this.A <= 4) Sombra.fg8();
  
  this.A+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.A > 4) this.A= 0;
 },
 derecha: function() {
  
  if (this.D <= 1) Sombra.fg10();
  else if (this.D <= 2) Sombra.fg11();
  else if (this.D <= 3) Sombra.fg12();
  else if (this.D <= 4) Sombra.fg11();
  
  this.D+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.D > 4) this.D= 0;
 }
};
var foo= function() {
 c.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
 
 if(Animar.dir == 83) Sombra.fg2();
 if(Animar.dir == 87) Sombra.fg5();
 if(Animar.dir == 65) Sombra.fg8();
 if(Animar.dir == 68) Sombra.fg11();
 
 if(Animar.tecla == 83) {Animar.abajo(); Imagen.auxy[1]+= Imagen.vel.des;}
 if(Animar.tecla == 87) {Animar.arriba(); Imagen.auxy[1]+= -Imagen.vel.des}
 if(Animar.tecla == 65) {Animar.izquierda(); Imagen.auxy[0]+= -Imagen.vel.des *1.5;}
 if(Animar.tecla == 68) {Animar.derecha(); Imagen.auxy[0]+= Imagen.vel.des *1.5;}
 
 requestAnimationFrame(foo);
};
var c= Lienzo.obj.getContext('2d');

Imagen.cargar();
foo();

onkeydown= function(e){Animar.tecla= e.keyCode; Animar.dir=0;};
onkeyup= function(){Animar.dir= Animar.tecla; Animar.tecla= 0;};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background:rgb(57,63,76);color:rgb(190,190,190);">
 <canvas id="lienzo" width="600" height="300" style="background:olivedrab;"></canvas>
 <script src="imagen.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
<!-- 
 Imagen
  obj
  ruta
  cargar()
  ini[]
  fin[]
  pos[]
  
 Lienzo
  obj
  ancho
  alto
  
 Sombra
  fg1, fg2, fg3 // abajo
  fg4, fg5, fg6 // arriba
  fg7, fg8, fg9 // izquierda
  fg10,fg11,fg12// derecha
  
 Movimiento
  N
  abajo()
 -->
```

Comment: I tried your snippet and everything looks ok here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the issue with the only key 'D' but it's happening with all image drawings.

Issue is that canvas is trying to smooth your images during `drawImage` calls. It can be disabled by setting following property to false.

```
//Following needs to be set to false, as pointed out by Kaiido, prefixed versions are necessary currenlty
c.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
c.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
c.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
c.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Here's the [documentation link from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled)

After disabling the smoothening images look alright. See the try the modified script below. I have code to disable the smoothening only.

```js
var Imagen= { // image to load, and manipulate
 obj: null,
 ruta: null,
 cargar: function() {
  this.obj= new Image();
  //this.obj.src= '/C:/Documents and Settings/casa/Mis documentos/Mis imágenes/sprite.png';
  this.obj.src= 'https://s22.postimg.org/6r8uzrygh/sprite.png';
 },
 ini: [2, 1],
 fin: [22, 38],
 pos: [0, 1],
 auxy: [0, 1],
 vel: {
  des: 0.4,
  som: 0.1
 }
};
var Lienzo= { // this is the canvas
 obj: document.getElementById('lienzo'),
 ancho: 600,
 alto: 300
};
var Sombra= { // this is for the sprites
 fg1: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*0; // recortes de la imagen
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1; // recortes de la imagen
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg2: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*1;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg3: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*2;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg4: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*3;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg5: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*4;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg6: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*5;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg7: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*6;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg8: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*7;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg9: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*8;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= Imagen.auxy[0];
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
 },
 fg10: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*6;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= -Imagen.auxy[0] -22;
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.save();
  c.translate(0, 0);
  c.scale(-1 ,1);
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
  c.restore();
 },
 fg11: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*7;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 0;
  Imagen.pos[0]= -Imagen.auxy[0] -22;
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1] -1;
  c.save();
  c.translate(0, 0);
  c.scale(-1 ,1);
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
  c.restore();
 },
 fg12: function() {
  Imagen.ini[0]= 2 +48*8;
  Imagen.ini[1]= 1;
  Imagen.pos[0]= -Imagen.auxy[0] -22;
  Imagen.pos[1]= Imagen.auxy[1];
  c.save();
  c.translate(0, 0);
  c.scale(-1 ,1);
  c.drawImage(Imagen.obj, Imagen.ini[0], Imagen.ini[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1], Imagen.pos[0], Imagen.pos[1], Imagen.fin[0], Imagen.fin[1]);
  c.restore();
 }
};
var Animar= { // a=65, d=68, w=87, s=83 // izq=37, arr=38, der=39, abj=40 this is for calling the sprites
 S: 0,
 W: 0,
 A: 0,
 D: 0,
 tecla: 0, dir: 83,
 abajo: function() {
  
  if (this.S <= 1) Sombra.fg1();
  else if (this.S <= 2) Sombra.fg2();
  else if (this.S <= 3) Sombra.fg3();
  else if (this.S <= 4) Sombra.fg2();
  
  this.S+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.S > 4) this.S= 0;
 },
 arriba: function() {
  
  if (this.W <= 1) Sombra.fg4();
  else if (this.W <= 2) Sombra.fg5();
  else if (this.W <= 3) Sombra.fg6();
  else if (this.W <= 4) Sombra.fg5();
  
  this.W+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.W > 4) this.W= 0;
 },
 izquierda: function() {
  
  if (this.A <= 1) Sombra.fg7();
  else if (this.A <= 2) Sombra.fg8();
  else if (this.A <= 3) Sombra.fg9();
  else if (this.A <= 4) Sombra.fg8();
  
  this.A+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.A > 4) this.A= 0;
 },
 derecha: function() {
  
  if (this.D <= 1) Sombra.fg10();
  else if (this.D <= 2) Sombra.fg11();
  else if (this.D <= 3) Sombra.fg12();
  else if (this.D <= 4) Sombra.fg11();
  
  this.D+= Imagen.vel.som;
  if (this.D > 4) this.D= 0;
 }
};
var foo= function() {
 c.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 300);
 
 if(Animar.dir == 83) Sombra.fg2();
 if(Animar.dir == 87) Sombra.fg5();
 if(Animar.dir == 65) Sombra.fg8();
 if(Animar.dir == 68) Sombra.fg11();
 
 if(Animar.tecla == 83) {Animar.abajo(); Imagen.auxy[1]+= Imagen.vel.des;}
 if(Animar.tecla == 87) {Animar.arriba(); Imagen.auxy[1]+= -Imagen.vel.des}
 if(Animar.tecla == 65) {Animar.izquierda(); Imagen.auxy[0]+= -Imagen.vel.des *1.5;}
 if(Animar.tecla == 68) {Animar.derecha(); Imagen.auxy[0]+= Imagen.vel.des *1.5;}
 
 requestAnimationFrame(foo);
};
var c= Lienzo.obj.getContext('2d');

 //Following needs to be set to false, as pointed out by Kaiido, prefixed versions are necessary currenlty
 c.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 c.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 c.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
 c.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

Imagen.cargar();
foo();

onkeydown= function(e){Animar.tecla= e.keyCode; Animar.dir=0;};
onkeyup= function(){Animar.dir= Animar.tecla; Animar.tecla= 0;};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background:rgb(57,63,76);color:rgb(190,190,190);">
 <canvas id="lienzo" width="600" height="300" style="background:olivedrab;"></canvas>
 <script src="imagen.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
<!-- 
 Imagen
  obj
  ruta
  cargar()
  ini[]
  fin[]
  pos[]
  
 Lienzo
  obj
  ancho
  alto
  
 Sombra
  fg1, fg2, fg3 // abajo
  fg4, fg5, fg6 // arriba
  fg7, fg8, fg9 // izquierda
  fg10,fg11,fg12// derecha
  
 Movimiento
  N
  abajo()
 -->
```

Comment: This property is still prefixed in some of the major browsers. (actually I think only chrome has an unprefixed version of it)

Comment: I tried it with the firefox and chrome, don't know about other browsers.

Comment: Well in Firefox, it gets unprefixed only in Aurora channel (Nightly builds), main channel (the one most uses) still has the prefixed version `mozImageSmoothingEnabled`. Other browsers do support it quite well, but with prefix : `msImageSmoothingEnabled`, and `webkitImageSmoothingEnabled` .

Comment: You're absolutely right, I checked again and it's not present on mozilla yet. Edited the code to disable prefixed version also.

Comment: Hey it worked for me, I use firefox. thanks a lot. Im newbie manipulating the canvas element